# Why it this probability problem solved in this weird way?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, problem-solving

So the task says, we throw a cube until number 1 occurs, what is probability that an even number occured.

My logic of solving was this, let C = an even number occur, so we may get even number in two throws
so P(c1) = $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{6}$ (probability that even number appeared * probability that 1 appeared), we can get even number in three throws p(c2) = $\frac{1}{2} *\frac{5}{6} * \frac{1}{6} $ ,we can get even number in 4 throws P(c2) =  $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{5}{6}*\frac{5}{6} * \frac{1}{6} $ we did $  \frac{5}{6}$  because when even number occured we don't care what number occur after that as long as it is not one because we are doing it in 4 throws, same for the 5 throw, 6 throws and so on, so P(c) =  $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{6}$ + $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{5}{6} * \frac{1}{6} $ + ...
P(c)  = $\frac{1}{2} * \frac{1}{6}* (1 + {(\frac{5}{6}})^1  + {(\frac{5}{6}})^2$ .... = geometric sequence = $\frac{1}{1-\frac{5}{6}}$  *$\frac{1}{3} * \frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{2} $

This make perfectly sense to me however their solution is this,https://imgur.com/TEuMI0F , their logic is that they calculated when even number will not appear, and then subtract one by that and get $\frac{3}{4}$, which also makes sense, the problem is my solution and their solution makes sense but I don't know where is the problem in my solution because the results were not the same

Thank you!

Comment: You forgot to take into account _where_ the even number you're tracking occurred, and this approach will lead to double-counting. Consider the first two throws of the three-throw case; you claim that there are $2\times 5$ out of the $6\times 6$ throws that have an even number in them (and no 1), but the number is much higher than that - out of the $5\times 5$ possibilities that have no 1, only $2\times 2=4$ of them have no even numbers, so there are 21 possible 'valid' two-throw sequences (then followed by a 1), not the 10 you obtain.

Comment: Also, on a very basic level: the probability that an even number occurs is $\frac12$, not $\frac13$, but even factoring that in your analysis is incorrect.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki solution is 3/4

Comment: Yes, I understand that — I was trying to point to a _specific_ subcase (the one where it takes exactly three rolls to get to a 1) and explaining why your counting in that case differs from the 'correct' counting in that case. The other cases are all wrong in similar fashion.

Comment: Yes i meant 1/2 * 1/6 for the first case and so on, will edit it, tnx

Comment: You could also tell that $\frac 12$ had to be wrong because $\frac 12$ is the probability of rolling an even number on a single roll, and the probability of rolling an even before a $1$ has to be larger than that.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki You are right, my comment deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first consider an easier problem, where you assume that you do exactly $n$ throws. This means the last roll is a $1$, none of the first $n-1$ rolls were a $1$, and you want the probability that one of the rolls was even. Then it is equivalent to roll a d5 with sides 2-6 $n-1$ times and ask whether at least one of those rolls is even.

The easiest way to do that while avoiding a double counting error is this "take the complement of the event that none of these rolls were even" trick. The alternative is a big messy inclusion-exclusion problem. Doing that, the probability that an even number showed up would be $1-(2/5)^{n-1}$. (As a sanity check, when $n=1$ this is $0$ as it should be because $n=1$ implies the first throw was a $1$ and $1$ is not even.)

Now we use the easy problem to solve this problem. The probability distribution of the number of throws total is geometric with parameter $1/6$, so the probability of $n$ throws is $(5/6)^{n-1} (1/6)$. We already conditioned on the number of throws earlier, so by the total probability formula, the overall desired probability is

$$\frac{1}{6} \sum_{n=1}^\infty (1-(2/5)^{n-1}) (5/6)^{n-1}=\frac{1}{6} \left ( \sum_{n=0}^\infty (5/6)^n - \sum_{n=0}^\infty (1/3)^n \right ) \\
= \frac{1}{6} \left ( \frac{1}{1-5/6} - \frac{1}{1-1/3} \right ) = \frac{1}{6} \left ( 6 - \frac{3}{2} \right ) = \frac{3}{4}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Here is another alternative. Define $p$ as the probability we are looking for. There are several possible first throw:

1. The first throw is even with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. After this we continue rolling the dice until $1$ appear.
2. The first throw is either $3$ or $5$. The probability is $\frac{1}{3}$. After this we continue rolling the dice until $1$ appear with probability $p$ that we have even number.

$$
\begin{align}
p&=\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}p\\
\\
p&=\frac{3}{4}
\end{align}
$$